# Tabhost/spec vs. viewpage vs tabbed actionbar ..which one?

Tags: android, android-tabs

I have been familiar with TabHost/TabSpec to create application with tabs. I noticed that there are more than one option to create tabs:

1- Tabs in action bar

2- Viewpager (I guess google calls it horizontal pager)

3- And offcourse the tabhost/tabspec approach.

I tried to read google docs but it is like everywhere so I got further confused.
When would you use what or is there one that is the norm?

Thanks

Comment: Tabhosts/Tabspec haven't been a thing in Android since 2011/Gingerbread (v9).... ViewPager with fragments and tabs is the way to go, and it is backwards compatible to android v4

Comment: Action bar tabs are deprecated

Comment: Thanks CQM, so viewpager with tabs as part of action bar or alone?

Comment: @karaokyo  how come ? It is in the design guidelines of android (the new docs)

Comment: I am talking specifically about action bar tabs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS.

Comment: Oh wow , that's new! Whats with adding and deprecating things :S. Thanks _!

Comment: ActionBar is not recommended anymore.  Toolbar is the new de-facto standard, as it can do everything that ActionBar can, and more.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Please put it as an answer with links or sample and I will accept it. Thanks for the hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a Toolbar with a ViewPager to simulate tabs (all wrapped in an AppBarLayout).  The result will look something like this:
[image]

You can read more about this type of design on the Material Design spec: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage

Also, here is a good tutorial on how to implement tabs within a ViewPager: http://blog.grafixartist.com/material-design-tabs-with-android-design-support-library/